# Check time changing automatic

Tags: php

There is a streaming channel which displays for 24 hours per day and I want to display that for certain hours of day in my website. I use a code as bellow:

```
$now = date('G',time());
$start = 13;
$end = 14;
if($now >= $start && $now <= $end){ 
    echo "streaming video";
}
else{
echo "image";
}
```

It works when I do refresh/load page. But I want this program to check the time and do reactions without it is needed to do reload the page. So, when the time comes up to 14:00 the video will not being displayed anymore but the image instead of video and when the time comes to 13:00 to display video instead of image. Can be done with php or it is needed ajax or something else?
Waiting for some help.

Comment: check output buffering and php sleep function and you will get there :)

Comment: You will be needing javascript to do this. Or you will need to cut off the stream somehow. Depends on how you are working.

Comment: @Jerodec The streaming isn't in my control. That's why I'm looking a way.

Comment: @randomizer Can you give an example? I think the output buffering checks if there is streaming action. The problem is that there is streaming action 24hours per day from that web channel and I want to display that to my website only a specific hour of day.

Comment: I probably think that an ajax solution is easier. See my answer for a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript function that performs an ajax call to a time function which can decide to set the stream or an image:

```
<div id="stream-content"></div>

setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/gettime.php",
        type: 'GET',        
        success: function(data){                    
        //check time, if correct, set video to the div #stream-content otherwise, set an image as the content
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: To be honest, I am confused. I don't know to use ajax.
May you do that example more simple? For instance give different colors instead of video and image if it is easier to you.
url stays as "/gettime" or it grabs webpage's time?

Comment: You perform an ajax call to a php page which returns the server time. You can parse this time in your success function and decide what to do with it. Set an image as content of your div or set a video as content.

Comment: This is my code on time.php -> `<?php
$b = time (); print date("H:i",$b) . "<br>"; 
?>`

Comment: And this in main page -> `<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/time.php",
        type: 'GET',        
        success: function(data){                    
         if($b>10:00){
          document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="none";
         }else{
          document.getElementById("liveTV_api").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("adtv").style.display="none";
         }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
<script>` 
So, What is wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is the succes or the error result?

Comment: [ERROR] time 10:40:31.193 :: org.flowplayer.rtmp::SubscribingRTMPConnectionProvider : received onFCSubscribe